# Show that the following functions are representable in K

Tags: number-theory, logic, proof-writing

Let K be a theory with equality in the language $\mathcal{L}_A$. Show that the following functions are representable in K.

(a) $Z_n(x_1, ..., x_n)=0$

is representable by wf $$x_1 = x_1 \land x_2=x_2 \land ... \land x_n=x_n \land y=0 $$
For any $k_1,...,k_n, m \in \mathbb{N}$. If $Z(k_1,...,k_n)=m$ then $m=0$ and $\vdash_K \bar{k_1},...,\bar{k_n}=\bar{k_1},...,\bar{k_n} \land 0=0$

We also have for any numeral $k_1,...,k_n$
$$ (\exists_1 y )  (\bar{k_1},...,\bar{k_n} = \bar{k_1},...,\bar{k_n} \land y=0) $$
Thus the function is representable in K

(b) $C_k^n(x_1,...,x_n)=k$, where $k$ is a fixed natural number.(Hint: Use
mathematical induction in the metalanguage with respect to k )

I think I did (a) correctly, but how do I start with (b)?
By which wf is $C_k^n(x_1,...,x_n)$ representable

Comment: Basically $Z_n$ is simply $C_0^n$...

Comment: Step 1: For k=0, it is true by (a).
Step 2: Assume it is true for k. Thus $C_k^n(x_1,...,x_n)=k$ is true.
We have to prove $C_{k+1}^n(x_1,...,x_n)=k+1$

Comment: And then prove it by the wf $x_1=x_1 \land x_2=x_2 \land... \land x_n=x_n \land y=k+1$?